# Segmentation fault while trying to build Unreal Engine

Tags: compiling, c++, segmentation-fault, engine

I'm following a tutorial at https://wiki.unrealengine.com/Building_On_Linux on building Unreal Engine on Linux. However, the step after the make command, it gives a segmentation fault and says the core is dumped. What does this mean and how do I fix it?

Comment: If you have Ubuntu 14.04 LTS or 16.04 LTS the problem may be caused by new kernel updates. See [Bug #1699772: linux-image-4.4.0-81-generic, linux-image-3.13.0-121-generic Regression: many user-space apps crashing](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1699772).

Comment: I have not tried again since posting this post but I've managed to make an even worse problem. https://askubuntu.com/questions/928945/opengl-version-not-found

Comment: Send the log files please, I can help you with this.